# Atom Editor Javascript - invalid or unexpected tokens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, atom-editor

I got a weird error on the web.

The code I wrote

```
document.body.appendBefore(wrapperDiv, document.body.firstChild);
```

The code the browser gets

```
document.body.appendBefore(wrapperDiv, document.body.firstChiâ€Œâ€‹ld);
```

My Atom editor is using UTF-8. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what plugins you're using with Atom or whatever programming language you're building this on top of, but there may be some type of code minification that's taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close all of your atom instances. Launch it with --safe option.

If this solves your issue, search for that added string on your atom directory:
Open Settings, click the "Open Config folder" button, open the file tree, right click at the .atom entry at its top and select "Search in Directory".

It may be a corrupted package or a wild edit unseen while using multiple cursors.